# OData search on transformed properties

Tags: rest, odata

We serve json objects over a OData REST API. The rough structure of an object looks like below

{
    "Property1": "Value1",
    "Property2": {
        "InterestingProperty": "/text1/part1/text2/part2"
    }
}

The values "part1" and "part2" are the ones I am interested in and from the back end they are indexed together.

I need to design the List API which can allow filtering of the objects which contain both the part1 and part2 in that particular property.
Any guidance on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this on the client side with the [`$filter` query option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398301) and the built-in `contains` function. For example,

```
GET http://host/MyObjects?$filter=contains(Property2/InterestingProperty,'part1') and contains(Property2/InterestingProperty,'part2')
```

However, this approach does allow for false positives; e.g., if the value of `InterestingProperty` is something like `/text1/part1/text2/part234`.

Perhaps a better approach is to define a server-side [OData function](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398351) to do custom filtering. This would allow you to have fine-grain control over matching against `InterestingProperty`. A function named `CustomFilter` in the `MyService` namespace and bound to the `MyObjects` entity set, would be invoked as follows:

```
GET http://host/MyObjects/MyService.CustomFilter
```

If you are using the .NET implementation of OData, there is a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) to get you started writing OData functions.